# Dynamic Hyperlink is not getting visible in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show dynamic hyperlink on each row of a dynamic gridview using below code but it is not showing the hyperlink.

```
gvdates.DataSource = xyz;
var m = tool.ToolsID;
HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
hp.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
hp.NavigateUrl = "~/OutageInfo.aspx?name=m;" + hp.Text;
e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(hp);
gvdates.DataBind();
e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(gvdates);
```

Comment: What is `e`? Where is this code located?

Comment: gvdates.databind()  ??

Comment: I have not posted the whole code..i am asking about the hyperlink part

Comment: @user635545: you have posted non-existing code but you expect us to fix the existing code. I've tried my best below.

Comment: gvdates is a gridview and i am using it to bind the columns.

Comment: Focus was on hyperlink thats why i have posted that part only. Let me try your solution. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create dynamic controls in [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) instead of [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) because this event gets fired on every postback whereas `RowDataBound` only will fire when the `GridView` gets databound to it's `DataSource`.

Dynamically created controls must be recreated on every postback with the same ID as before, then they retain their values in the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) and events will fire correctly.

So you should create them in `RowCreated` and "fill" them in `RowDataBound`(f.e. the HyperLink's `NavigateUrl` if it's from the datasource).

However, you should add dynamic controls **after** you have databound the `GridView`. So this seems to be pointless (whatever `e` is):

```
e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(hp);
gvdates.DataBind();
```